# How to add scriptlet in include in jsp?

Tags: jsp

How can we add scriplet in include?

For example:

```
<@include file="../../../sample/Includes/util.jsp">
```

Now I want to add context path in this:

```
request.getContextPath()

<@include file="request.getContextPath()/sample/Includes/util.jsp">
```

but I got some error.

Answer (score 0):

Includes are context-relative, so you should just prefix a forward slash and you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Static include are always relative.

- If the relative URL starts with /, the path is relative to the JSP application's context, which is a javax.servlet.ServletContext object that is in turn stored in the application object.
- If the relative URL starts with a directory or file name, the path is relative to the JSP file

The pathname to the included file, which is always a relative URL. Simply put, a relative URL is just the path segment of an URL, without a protocol, port, or domain name, like this:

- "error.jsp"
- "/templates/onlinestore.html"
- "/beans/calendar.jsp"

[Source](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm6.html)